# Unable to marshal Java class when @XmlRootElement annotation is present

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, netbeans-platform

I am writing a netbeans platform application using nebteans 8.1, Java 1.8 under CentOS6.4.

I have a Java class that looks like this (import classes omitted):

```
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "module-task")
public class MyTask extends BaseClass {
    // methods, members
}
```

When I try marshalling it using JAXBContext, I get an error message claiming it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation (when clearly there is one from the previous code snippet).

Can anyone suggest why the @XmRootElement annotation is not being recognised?

Comment: Those imports might be important...

Answer (score 1):

You're not implementing `Serializable`. That is the cause, because transforming the state of your object to XML is basically just a different way of serializing it.

Add `implements java.io.Serializable` and if you don't want to provide a `serialVersionUUID`, also add a `@SuppressWarnings("serial")` annotation on the class.

This should take care of it.